# Useful PowerPoint keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I've found that many PowerPoint users don't know any useful keyboard shortcuts and always have to fiddle around with the mouse to start the presentation. It's also fun to watch people stepping back through a lengthy presentation to get to slide number X, going through all the animations backwards etc...

Among the best shortcuts I've found so far are

**During presentations**

<kbd>.</kbd> to blank the screen to black

<kbd>,</kbd> to blank the screen to white

<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to slide number 12

**In Editing mode**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the presentation from the current slide (as opposed to <kbd>F5</kbd> that always starts at slide number 1)

but I guess there are a lot more that I haven't found yet. What do you use?

Comment: Also, the knowledge that you just have to rename a *.ppt file to *.pps to make the presentation start right after double-clicking the file seems not to be very prevalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**During Presentations:**

<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>=</kbd> : Show / Hide Pointer

<kbd>E</kbd> : Erase Screen Annotations

<kbd>H</kbd> : Advance to Hidden Slide

<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>PERIOD</kbd> : Display a black screen, or return to the slide show from a black screen

<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>COMMA</kbd> : Display a white screen, or return to the slide show from a white screen

<kbd>TAB</kbd> : Go to the first or next hyperlink on a slide

For the complete list of PowerPoint keyboard shortcuts, check [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint/HP051955191033.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

What drives me nuts is when people search for the right arrow key during a presentation instead of simply hitting <kbd>space</kbd> to get to the next slide.